# How can I reduce excessive spacing between text elements in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my React Native project, I'm encountering an issue where there's excessive spacing between text elements, causing an undesirable layout. Despite attempts to adjust styles, the spacing remains larger than intended, impacting the overall aesthetics and user experience. How can I effectively address this problem and achieve a more compact arrangement of text elements within my app?

I tried adjusting the style properties of the text elements, such as line height, in an attempt to reduce the space between them. I expected that by decreasing these values, the spacing between the texts would be reduced to desired levels, allowing for a more compact layout. However, despite my efforts, the spacing still remained wider than desired, compromising the intended layout and user experience. I also noticed that even when removing properties like line height, the spacing between text elements remained the same, suggesting a default setting. Thus, I'm considering reducing it, possibly by utilizing negative margin-top values to achieve the desired spacing between the text elements.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90fSH.png)

Comment: Consider this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: You are able to control by setting lineHeight really. Please share your code and text styles.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share minimal codes. Might be issue with your styling, maybe you are using margin between both of the codes.